# Flutter callback to parent throws nosuchmethoderror

Tags: flutter, callback

I am trying to understand how callbacks work and have read everything I can. However my code does not work.
I have a "product" parent that shows the fixed parts of the view, however I then either show the "list" or "edit" child. "list" is shown when there is no productToEdit, "edit" is shown when there is. product to edit is a global.

Parent

```
class Products extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
   return _ProductsState();
 }
}

class _ProductsState extends State<Products> {

 _callBackFromProductEdit() {
   print("_callBackFromProductEdit");
   setState(() {
   });
 }
 _callBackFromProductList() {
   print("_callBackFromProductList");
   setState(() {
   });
 }

 Container getProductContainer(){
   if(globals.productToEdit.toString() != "null"){
     return Container(
       child: ProductEditView(callBackToProduct: _callBackFromProductEdit(),),
     );
   }else{
     print('getProductContainer ProductListView' );
     return Container(
       child: ProductListView(callBackToProductFromList: _callBackFromProductList()),
     );
   }
 }
```

and the child

```
class ProductListView extends StatefulWidget {
 final Function callBackToProductFromList;
 ProductListView({Key key, this.callBackToProductFromList}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
   return _ProductListState();
 }
}

class _ProductListState extends State<ProductListView> {

 @override
 void initState(){
   super.initState();
 }

 void callingBackToParentFromList(String productId){
   print("callingBackToParent");
   globals.productToEdit=productId;
   print("with ${globals.productToEdit}");
   widget.callBackToProductFromList();
 }


 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(

--- Lots of layout code ---

   child: SizedBox(
      width: 50,
      height: 20,
      child:RaisedButton(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),),
          onPressed: (){
              print('edit ${productList[i]['id'].toString()}');
              globals.productToEdit=productList[i]['id'].toString();
              widget.callBackToProductFromList();
              //callingBackToParentFromList(productList[i]['id'].toString());
 ---- a bit more code -----
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

To my eye and what I read, this should work.

child: ProductListView(callBackToProductFromList: _callBackFromProductList()),

means

creates a child using the ProductListView class attaching what ProductListView calls the callback to Products method to execute on callback.

final Function callBackToProductFromList;ProductListView({Key key, this.callBackToProductFromList}) : super(key: key);

means

ProductListView widget declared a function called callBackToProductFromList
then
sets this function as that the parent must connect to

then
widget.callBackToProductFromList();

means

execute the function that the widget declared.

However, on pressing the Edit button, the console shows

edit 5e5575221e4b5c28b2ea88de
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
'callBackToProductFromList'
Dynamic call of null.
Receiver: Instance of 'ProductListView'
Arguments: []

So, I have the string, however the error says that callBackToParentFromList does not exist as a method.

There is obviously a gap in my understanding. If possible, could someone explain why it is broken, rather than just code a solution as I believe my understanding of this is correct according to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

child: ProductListView(callBackToProductFromList: _callBackFromProductList()),

should be

child: ProductListView(callBackToProductFromList: _callBackFromProductList),

with the () you will call the function immediately and not pass the function it self